# How to assign a new column to a dataframe based on comparison between other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

In my one sheet Excel file that I created through my SQL, I have 3 columns that represent letter ratings. The rating values may differ between ratings 1, 2, and 3, but they can still be ranked with the same value.

I am trying to create a new column in my Excel file that can take these 3 letter ratings and pull the middle rating.

```
 ranking       | Rating_1 | Rating_2 | Rating_3 | NEW_COLUMN    |
   (1 lowest)  | -------- | -------- | -------- | --------      |
        3      |    A+    |   AA     |    Aa    | middle(rating)|
        2      |    B+    |   BB     |    Bb    | middle(rating)|
        1      |    Fa    |   Fb     |    Fc    | middle(rating)|
               | -------- | -------- | -------- | ---------     |
```

There are three scenarios I need to account for:

1. if all three ratings differ, pick the rating between rating_1, rating_2, and rating_3 that isn't the highest rating or the lowest rating
2. if all three ratings are the same, pick rating on rating_1
3. if 2 of the ratings are the same, but one is different, pick the minimum rating

I created a dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Rating_1": ["A+", "AA", "Aa"],
     "Rating_2": ["B+", "BB", "Bb"],
     "Rating_3": ["Fa", "Fb", "Fc"]}
)
df["NEW COLUMN"] = {insert logic here}
```

Or is it easier to create a new DF that filters down the the original DF?

Answer (score 0):

With the fowllowing toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Rating_1": ["A+", "Cc", "Aa"],
        "Rating_2": ["AA", "Cc", "Aa"],
        "Rating_3": ["BB", "Cc", "Bb"],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output
  Rating_1 Rating_2 Rating_3
0       A+       AA       BB
1       Cc       Cc       Cc
2       Aa       Aa       Bb
```

Here is one way to do it using Python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to check conditions:

```py
# First condition
df["Middle_rating"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: sorted([x["Rating_1"], x["Rating_2"], x["Rating_3"]])[1]
    if len(set([x["Rating_1"], x["Rating_2"], x["Rating_3"]])) == 3
    else "",
    axis=1,
)

# Second condition
df["Middle_rating"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["Rating_1"]
    if len(set([x["Rating_1"], x["Rating_2"], x["Rating_3"]])) == 1
    else x["Middle_rating"],
    axis=1,
)

# Third condition
ratings = {
    rating: i
    for i, rating in enumerate(["A+", "AA", "Aa", "B+", "BB", "Bb", "C+", "CC", "Cc"])
}  # ratings ordered from best (A+: 0) to worst (CC: 8)
df["Middle_rating"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: max(x["Rating_1"], x["Rating_2"], x["Rating_3"])
    if len(
        set([ratings[x["Rating_1"]], ratings[x["Rating_2"]], ratings[x["Rating_3"]]])
    )
    == 2
    else x["Middle_rating"],
    axis=1,
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
  Rating_1 Rating_2 Rating_3 Middle_rating
0       A+       AA       BB            AA
1       Cc       Cc       Cc            Cc
2       Aa       Aa       Bb            Bb
```